# MS Access How to get the sum of each products of rows combination?

Tags: ms-access, combinations

Suppose I have a table with a field Value: v1, v2, v3, v4

when combines 2 rows:
sum = v1*v2 + v1*v3 + ... + v3*v4

when combines 3 rows:
sum = v1*v2*v3 + v1*v2*v3 + ... + v2*v3*v4

Basically get combination of all rows first, and then get sum of each combination's product. I have written a vba class for this task, but it's very clumsy, just calculate every combination one by one. I would like to know is there any easier way to do this job? SQL query or linear algebra, any way could simplified the process is welcomed. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

MS Access isn't really capable of doing this without VBA.  JET SQL is capable of SUMming data in an aggregate, but there is no Product aggregate, and JET SQL doesn't support user-defined aggregates.

If you post your code, someone may be able to suggest improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Monty Wild, I've figured it out.

`SELECT sum(t1.value*t2.value) AS aggrSum

FROM tbl AS t1

INNER JOIN tbl AS t2

ON t1.ID<t2.ID;`
note tbl.ID should be unique.